# Longest substring with consecutive repetitions

Tags: algorithms, optimization, strings, substrings, longest-common-substring

I want to find the longest substring which is repeated without any gap between the repetitions.  That is, given a string $x$, I want to find the longest $y$ such that $yy$ is a substring of $x$.

What I mean is the following cases:

```
In "aa"         I want "a"    with a position of 0 and repetition of 2
In "aaab"       I want "a"    with a position of 0 and repetition of 3
In "abc"        I want ""     (false or whatever)
In "abababc"    I want "ab"   with a position of 0 and repetition of 3
In "aaabbbb"    I want "b"    with a position of 3 and repetition of 4
In "eabcdabcde" I want "abcd" with a position of 1 and repetition of 2
In "cababcab"   I want "ab"   with a position of 1 and repetition of 2 (not 3, because of the "c" between the three "ab"'s)
```

I've been looking at various suffix and prefix algorithms, but none of them has the "no gaps" part build into it. Both [LCP arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LCP_array) and [Suffix arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_array) seems to suffer from this.

Googling for "Longest repeated substrings" gives me algorithms which e.g. find `"hello"` in `"abcdehellofghijhelloklmn"`, but this is *not* what I want.

Comment: Oh, I see. Anyway, a suffix tree holds all the information you need; the deepest inner nodes with children that have fitting indices. The question is how you augment the tree so that this property is easy to check for each node.

Comment: While discussing my problem with my colleagues, we found that some of the behavior of our wanted algorithm is unspecified. In the case of `ababababc`, we would actually must more prefer to get `ab` than `abab`. So we are actually looking for the shortest sequence in a repeated sequence in a string.

Comment: @MadsOhmLarsen Sure but any string that matches contains $y^n$ for $n\geq2$ also contains $yy$.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand you are looking for maximal substrings of the form $y^k$ for $k\ge 2$. By some this is called a *repetition* in a string. One of the first to give an algorithm for finding these is Maxime Crochemore: An optimal algorithm for computing all the repetitions in a word, Inform. Process. Lett. 12 (1981) 244-248. From what I understand his approach has been reformulated in terms of suffix trees and arrays.

Answer (score 0):

After fiddling a bit around with different options, we discovered, that what we really needed was as simple as the regular expression: `(.+)\1+`. This will match at least one character and then match at least one of the same match again.

Having `aaab` will then match the `a` which is present three times.

In `cababcab`, we match the first `ab` which is there twice and so on.

Sidenote: Now the next problem is implementing this for something other than strings and characters, e.g. C++ objects.